# Understanding various input lines types for mixing?

Tags: speakers, mixer, input, line-level

Can anyone out there point me to a good tutorial to understand the various kinds of inputs and outputs use in audio? I've looked around a little bit, and I have not found anything too great. Online is great, book recommendations are good as well.

I'm really trying to get a handle on the differences between things like line, mic, balanced / unbalance, etc.

I'm getting back into electronics / ham radio after a long hiatus. My ultimate goal is to create a setup that would that I can take the audio of a number of receivers, which typically have 1/8 or 1/4 inch jacks (stereo or mono) for headphones or external speakers, run them through a mixer, into something like a set of amplified computer speaker.

Thanks!

-Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great summary of the different signal levels:

> **Mic level** is the lowest, or weakest, level signal of the four and requires a preamplifier to bring it up to Line level.
>
> **Instrument level** signals live between mic and line level signals and have the most variation. You typically see this kind of signal
>   come from an electric guitar or bass. A preamplifier is required to
>   bring the signal up to line level.
>
> **Line level** signals are the highest level signals before amplification. This is the type of signal that typically flows through
>   your recording system after the preamplifier stage and before the
>   amplifier that powers your speakers.
>
> **Speaker level** signals are post amplification. After a line level signal enters an amplifier, it exists to the speakers at speaker
>   level. These signals are much higher in voltage than line level and
>   require speaker cables for safe signal transfer.

Highly recommend reading the source as it has some more info.

**Source**: https://www.sweetwater.com/sweetcare/articles/whats-the-difference-between-mic-instrument-line-and-speaker-level-signals/

---

Regarding **balanced** vs **unbalanced**:

Balanced audio cables help protect against electromagnetic interference. Electromagnetic interference can deterioate an audio signal and introduce noise when an audio signal travels over a long, unbalanced cable.

**Source**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_audio

---

Udemy has a free "Audio Engineering 101" course that teaches signal flow, this would definitely be a great place to start, especially as it's only 30 minutes long.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Chris - that did help. I was to rephrase my query based on the info you provided and found some good information.  I'll definitely check out the Udemy course as well.